# php pdf to text - getting rid of special characters

Tags: php

I am using a class found on phpclasses.org website, to convert my pdf docs to text. 
The resulting text has a bunch of fnny characters that looks like chinese or something in between the text. looking at the source: something like this: 茀 䠀 䠀 圀 䰀
Can someone please help me get rid of them, there are more, these are just a few I could type.
The php class: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31030.html

Comment: The best person to know the answer is the author of that class. You probably stumbled into a bug of the class and he is the most qualified person to fix it. Try asking directly in the [forum of the PDF to text class](http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/6155/) in the PHPClasses site itself. The author is notified by e-mail when a new message is posted there about his class. He has been quite active there, so you have great chances of getting support in this matter there.